# linux read cache with minimal setup

Tags: linux, cache

I've been trying to find a tool that lets me configure an read cache SSD for an HDD in my little home lab, which is running arch linux (yes...) with the system being installed to the HDD. I'm on a tight budget so I'd like to continue using cheap HDDs as much as possible, and an SSD cache would give me quite a performance benefit as I'm accessing e.g. nextcloud pretty much all the time.

`dm-cache` and `bcache` both require reformatting the backing drive. `enhanceio` seems unmaintained. Since I'm only trying to set up read caching I'm hoping to find an easier solution that lets me skip a lot of the setup and the related risks and problems.

I'm trying to avoid having to set up my whole system again, and thus I've been wondering: Are there any read-cache systems available for linux that require minimal setup and don't risk any data loss?